# Subtrair -1 do próprio valor do campo mySQL

Tags: mysql

Em um campo da tabela do tipo integer guarda a quantidade de itens em estoque, quando dou baixa, devo dar -1 do próprio campo, como fazer isso direto do mySQL?

Está correto desse modo?

```
UPDATE `tblQtd` SET `qtdItens` = (`qtdItens`-1) WHERE `idItenRef` = '".$id."' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Quando digitei o título da pergunta não houve sugestão de resposta semelhante, então inseri, sempre tomo cuidado para com isso, obrigado pela referência, apago a minha pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o que você comentou, a query seria desta forma:

```
"UPDATE tblQtd SET qtdItens = qtdItens-1 WHERE idItenRef = ".$id;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Comment: Isto não aparenta ser uma solução. Provavelmente ao trocar a query houve uma correção de outro problema de sintaxe - Qual seria o problema na query original que foi corrigido aqui?

Comment: @Bacco removeu ( .... ) da query e os acentos graves. Ainda dá para melhorar?

Comment: @EliseuB. a questão é que só mudou o estilo de código, e ainda removeu a segurança do LIMIT, mas aparentemente não trocou nada que efetivamente altere o comportamento da query. Minha dúvida maior aqui é saber se houve qualquer benefício e o que mudou de fato. Como você comentou que "deu certo" e a outra query também deveria ter dado certo, achei estranho o objetivo do post e as mudanças propostas. Lembrando ainda que, mesmo desnecessários os parênteses e os backticks, de qualquer forma isso não interfere em nada na execução da query.

Comment: @Bacco eu mantive o LIMIT por prevenção, tive problemas com condição de corrida em aplicações anteriores e aprendi com o erro e foi tempo queimado, e mantenho o acento grave por evitar conflitos, mas testei a minha e a dele e ambas deram certo, por falta de uma resposta detalhada fiquei com ela, mas não levou 'resposta aceita'.